# FutureWarning when applying a condition on a pandas dataframe to filter an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, future-warning

I have applied PCA to an array of around 1000 observations but only want to keep the observation in the new array IF one of the features from the original array = something.

I have a numpy array `df2` and a dataframe `df`. I want to find all rows in `df2` where `df.Position` is `CDM`.

My actual data:

```
df2

[[ -6.00987823e+00   4.46585005e+00]
 [ -7.09055159e+00   1.89437600e+00]
 [ -5.91044431e+00  -1.97888707e+00]
 [ -4.85698965e+00  -1.09936724e+00]
 [ -4.01780368e-01  -2.57178392e+00]
 [ -2.97351215e+00  -3.15940358e+00]
 [ -4.27973589e+00   2.82707326e+00]
 [  3.95086576e+00   1.08281922e+00]
 [ -2.94075361e+00  -1.95544661e+00]
 [ -4.83788056e+00   2.32369496e+00]
 [ -5.00473716e+00  -3.37680552e-01]
 [ -4.88905829e+00  -1.55527476e+00]
 [ -3.38202709e+00  -1.04402867e+00]
 [ -2.14261510e+00  -5.30757477e-01]
 [  3.00813803e-01  -2.11010985e+00]
 [ -2.67824986e+00  -1.83303905e+00]
 [ -1.64547049e+00  -2.48056250e+00]
 [ -2.92550543e+00  -3.02363170e+00]
 [ -4.01116933e+00   2.90363840e+00]
 [ -1.04571206e+00   7.58064433e-01]
 [  2.34068739e-01  -2.33981296e+00]
 [  3.15597517e+00   1.09429188e+00]
 [ -3.83828970e+00   1.14195305e-01]
 [ -7.33794066e-01  -3.70152816e+00]
 [  8.21789967e-01  -4.77818413e-01]
 [ -3.29257688e+00  -1.61887349e+00]
 [ -4.24297171e+00   2.27187714e+00]
 [  1.45714199e+00  -3.56024788e+00]
 [  1.79855738e+00  -3.71818328e-01]
 [  3.68171085e-01  -3.52961707e+00]
 [  3.77585412e+00  -3.01627595e-01]
 [ -4.21740128e+00  -1.30913719e+00]
 [ -3.85041585e+00  -1.05515969e+00]
 [ -5.01752378e+00   4.67348167e-01]
 [  3.65943448e+00   9.21016483e-01]
 [  3.12159896e+00  -1.25707872e-01]
 [ -4.50219722e+00  -4.06752784e+00]
 [ -3.92172250e+00  -2.88567430e+00]
 [ -2.68908475e-01  -2.17506629e+00]
 [ -1.13728112e+00  -2.66843007e+00]
 [ -8.73467957e-01  -1.24389494e+00]
 [  3.21966300e+00  -1.35271239e-01]
 [ -4.31060796e+00  -1.90505910e+00]
 [  3.73904981e+00   7.70228802e-01]
 [  1.02646986e+00  -5.91828676e-01]
 [  8.43840480e-01  -1.49636218e+00]
 [  1.54065978e+00  -1.65086030e+00]
 [  2.96602068e+00  -7.41024474e-01]
 [  6.53636345e-01   3.04647288e-01]
 [  2.59236989e+00  -6.70435261e-02]
 [  2.00184665e-01  -1.55230314e+00]
 [ -7.29533092e-01  -2.73390749e+00]
 [ -2.93578745e+00  -2.18118257e+00]
 [ -4.37481195e+00   1.02701222e+00]
 [  1.00713302e+00  -1.39943282e+00]
...]


df
```

(simply playing position in football/soccer - FB, CB, CDM, CM, AM, FW)

```
Position
FW
FW
FW
FW
FB
AM
FW
CB
AM
FW
AM
FW
AM
CM
FB
AM
CM
CM
FW
CM
CDM
CB
AM
FB
CDM
FW
FW
CDM
FB
CDM
CB
AM
...
AM
```

---

When filtering, I get this output (along with a `FutureWarning`):

[image]

Where am I going wrong and how can I filter the data appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FutureWarning` is probably a result of your `numpy` and `pandas` versions being out of date. You can upgrade them using:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy pandas
```

As for the filtering, there are quite a few options. Here I mention each one with some dummy data.

---

**Setup**

```
df
    name colour  a  b  c  d  e  f
0   john    red  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  james    red  2  3  4  5  6  7
2   jane   blue  1  2  3  5  7  8

df2
       0      1
0  0.122  0.222
1  0.343  0.345
2  0.345  0.563
```

**Option 1**
*`boolean indexing`*

```
df2[df.colour == 'red']
Out[726]: 
       0       1
0  0.122   0.222
1  0.343   0.345
```

**Option 2**
*`df.eval`*

```
df2[df.eval('colour == "red"')]
Out[732]: 
       0       1
0  0.122   0.222
1  0.343   0.345
```

Note that both these options work even if `df2` is a `numpy` array of the form:

```
array([[ 0.122,  0.222],
       [ 0.343,  0.345],
       [ 0.345,  0.563]])
```

---

For your actual data, you'll need to do something along the same lines:

```
df2

array([[-6.01 ,  4.466],
       [-7.091,  1.894],
       [-5.91 , -1.979],
       [-4.857, -1.099],
       [-0.402, -2.572],
       [-2.974, -3.159],
       [-4.28 ,  2.827],
       [ 3.951,  1.083],
       [-2.941, -1.955],
       [-4.838,  2.324],
       [-5.005, -0.338],
       [-4.889, -1.555],
       [-3.382, -1.044],
       [-2.143, -0.531],
       [ 0.301, -2.11 ],
       [-2.678, -1.833],
       [-1.645, -2.481],
       [-2.926, -3.024],
       [-4.011,  2.904],
       [-1.046,  0.758],
       [ 0.234, -2.34 ],
       [ 3.156,  1.094],
       [-3.838,  0.114],
       [-0.734, -3.702],
       [ 0.822, -0.478],
       [-3.293, -1.619],
       [-4.243,  2.272],
       [ 1.457, -3.56 ],
       [ 1.799, -0.372],
       [ 0.368, -3.53 ],
       [ 3.776, -0.302],
       [-4.217, -1.309]])

df

   Position
0        FW
1        FW
2        FW
3        FW
4        FB
5        AM
6        FW
7        CB
8        AM
9        FW
10       AM
11       FW
12       AM
13       CM
14       FB
15       AM
16       CM
17       CM
18       FW
19       CM
20      CDM
21       CB
22       AM
23       FB
24      CDM
25       FW
26       FW
27      CDM
28       FB
29      CDM
30       CB
31       AM

df2[df.Position == 'CDM']

array([[ 0.234, -2.34 ],
       [ 0.822, -0.478],
       [ 1.457, -3.56 ],
       [ 0.368, -3.53 ]])
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED hi, thanks for your answer. whilst the filtering works, the output of the new array means that each observation that meets the if condition has the same value, and those that don't have a different value. i have updated my post with what happens, if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd

d = {'d': [4, 5, 5],
     'a': [1, 2, 1], 
     'name': ['john', 'james', 'jane'], 
     'e': [5, 6, 7],
     'f': [6, 7, 8], 'c': [3, 4, 3], 
     'b': [2, 3, 2], 
     'colour': ['red', 'red', 'blue']}
cols = ['name', 'colour', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = cols)
print (df)
    name colour  a  b  c  d  e  f
0   john    red  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  james    red  2  3  4  5  6  7
2   jane   blue  1  2  3  5  7  8
```

---

```
#create mask by condition
mask = df['colour'] == 'red'
#for multiple values
#mask = df['colour'].isin(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: colour, dtype: bool

#filter only numeric values and convert to numpy array
arr = df.drop(['name','colour'], axis=1).values
print (arr)
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [2 3 4 5 6 7]
 [1 2 3 5 7 8]]

pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(arr)
print (pca.components_ )
[[-0.0463861  -0.0463861  -0.0463861  -0.35279184 -0.65919758 -0.65919758]
 [ 0.55515147  0.55515147  0.55515147  0.21897879 -0.11719389 -0.11719389]
 [ 0.62531284 -0.13184966 -0.136648   -0.71363037  0.17840759  0.17840759]]

#filter by condition
arr1 = pca.components_ [mask]
print (arr1)
[[-0.0463861  -0.0463861  -0.0463861  -0.35279184 -0.65919758 -0.65919758]
 [ 0.55515147  0.55515147  0.55515147  0.21897879 -0.11719389 -0.11719389]]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. whilst the filtering works, the output of the new array means that each observation that meets the if condition has the same value, and those that don't have a different value. i have updated my post with what happens, if you could help.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if understand. But one idea - is not possible filter before PCA like `arr = df.drop(['name','colour'], axis=1)[mask].values` and then use `pca = PCA(n_components=2)` ?

Comment: i want to filter AFTER the PCA on the WHOLE set, but i want to isolate the groups for various things post-PCA

Comment: OK, and why solution in my answer fail? Dont need filter rows by condition?

Comment: see my edit. both solutions from you and COLDSPEED did half the job. although it distinguishes the rows which meet the condition, it doesnt omit them from the output. Instead it for some reason sets the PCA "co-ordinates" for the observations that meet the condition as as the 2nd row co-ords and those observations that do not meet the condition as the 1st row co-ords